# how to deal with needing to declare members private only for the purpose of unit testing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, moq

On the one hand I do not want to expose my private members to the public, on the other hand if I make them private then unit testing is a pain.

For example if I have a class:

```
public class myClass
{
   public string myString{get;set;}
   public int myInt{get;set;}
}
```

If those can safely be converted to *privates*, my only hesitation would be that I would not be able to thoroughly unit test them.

**How do you factor your code with encapsulation in mind as well as TDD?**

Comment: If they're private there must still be a way to set them from the outside otherwise they will always be `null` and `0`. Your tests will just use that method.

Comment: Related - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126545/would-you-rather-make-private-stuff-internal-public-for-tests-or-use-some-kind. Perhaps even cross-site duplicate.